# How to have functionality for first and last page in MUI DataGrid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to have functionality for first and last page in MUI DataGrid but I don't find way to do that, I search in documentation and also in the previous questions but it seems that the DataGrid doesn't have this functionality.
Is it possible to do that.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Please check again `Data Grid - Pagination`, there is a option for custom pagination, They have example exactly for your case where the first 5 pages are shown also the last one.